# How can I implement locking a range of values in a sorted sequence?

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, concurrency

I am trying to write a general purpose locking algorithm which allows me to lock a range of contiguous values in a sorted array. To start with, these could be exclusive locks - so two concurrent locks must be non-overlapping. What could be a good, scalable algorithm to do this? (Scalable ~ concurrent)

A specific example could be locking a range of contiguous bytes in a file for writing.

Concretely:
Let's say `{a_i}` is a valid sequence, for `i` = 0 through `N-1`, such that:

1. `a_j < a_k` for all j, k such that `0 <= j < k < N`.
2. `lock(a_j, a_k)` locks all elements from `a_j` through `a_k`.
3. While the above lock is held, another request `lock(a_x, a_y)` will succeed *only if* either `a_x > a_k`, or else `a_y < a_j`.

Comment: You may want to clarify "scalable". Is it more about $N$ or about the number of locks?

Comment: I would say number of locks, more concurrent.